# What does "years off" mean?

Tags: technology

What does "years off" mean in a technological background? For example, I have encountered a sentence:

"Scientists had thought that the technology was years off."

I don't quite get what the accurate meaning of the phrase "years off". Does that mean it has pushed the work through a breakthrough?

Answer (score 2):

The usual expression is **years away**. The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/away) gives this example use

> Then there are areas with great potential for the future such as
>   genetics but that potential is years away.

It means that the technology won't be available for a long time.

This does mean the same as **years off** in the same context

> Scientists had thought that the technology was years off.

but **years off** can mean something different from a time in the future

> The archaeologist's estimate of the ruin's age was years off.

I can't a dictionary reference for these uses of **off**.

Comment: This answer is correct, but I don't think it makes it clear that "years off" means the same thing as "years away".